# Regular expression (optional) multiline java stacktrace

Tags: python, regex

This is my first question on stack overflow. I've allready found a lot of answers on stack overflow but not to this problem i'm having. (p.s. Thank you for all the good answers so far!!)

I'm building a log file parser which spews everything to graylog but i'm having difficulty matching multiline stacktraces (or multiline INFO messages).

Right now i have this piece of python code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^\[(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\] MW(\d*) P(\d*) PR(\d*)\] (.{5}) - (.*) - (.*)', re.MULTILINE)
colnames = ('day','month','year','hour','minute','second','medewerkerid','patientid','praktijkid','level','logger','short_message')
file = open('file.log.2013-12-03','r')
for line in file:
    match = pattern.match(line)
    if match:
            for item in match.groups():
                    print item
            print
```

The logfiles look like this:

```
[03/12/2013 00:20:09] MW310148720 P316855786 PR306788004] WARN  - o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
[03/12/2013 00:20:09] MW310148720 P316855786 PR306788004] WARN  - o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
[03/12/2013 00:20:09] MW310148720 P316855786 PR306788004] INFO  - n.p.a.w.c.agenda.AgendaKalenderCtrl - AgendaKalenderCtrl.perform(...) duurde 52 ms
[03/12/2013 00:20:22] MW310148720 P316855786 PR306788004] WARN  - o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
[03/12/2013 00:20:22] MW310148720 P316855786 PR306788004] WARN  - o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
[03/12/2013 00:20:22] MW310148720 P316855786 PR306788004] INFO  - n.p.a.w.c.agenda.AgendaKalenderCtrl - AgendaKalenderCtrl.perform(...) duurde 47 ms
[03/12/2013 00:22:18] MW310148720 P316855786 PR306788004] INFO  - nl.xxxxxxxx.authentication - Subject Subject:
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: agenda
    Principal: UserPrincipal: Ween
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: medicatievoorschrijven
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: versturenbbberichten
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: standaardvoorschriftvastleggen
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: facturatie
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: medischdossier
    Principal: ApplicationPrincipal: his
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: altijdherhalen
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: onderhoudpatienten
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: medicatieauthoriseren
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: zoekenpassant
    Principal: ActionPrincipal: rapportage
    Principal: WEB_BROWSER_CHROME
 is afgemeld
[03/12/2013 00:22:18] MW310148720 P316855786 PR306788004] INFO  - nl.xxxxxxxx.application - [LOGOFF]           User 'Ween' logged off.
[03/12/2013 06:40:59] MW310155226 P PR301914008] WARN  - n.p.a.b.a.jndi.JndiResourcesHelper - Getting 'threadPoolTimeout' from JNDI context failed. Using default value: 900
[03/12/2013 06:41:10] MW310155226 P PR301914008] WARN  - o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
[03/12/2013 06:41:10] MW310155226 P PR301914008] WARN  - o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
[03/12/2013 06:41:10] MW310155226 P PR301914008] INFO  - n.p.a.w.c.agenda.AgendaKalenderCtrl - AgendaKalenderCtrl.perform(...) duurde 33 ms
```

All the single log lines work fine. Eveything is split into the right amount of groups except for the multilines. I would like the multiline messages to be part of 1 additional group (it will be named full_message).

I've allready tried numerous things but my regular expression knowledge is not very good.

Could someone please advise?

Bassically what i want is at the end of any line, if the next line doesn't start with a bracket ( [ ) place that complete line in 1 group and all the following lines until we reach the bracket ( [ ).

I can do it with an else if the line doesn't match, but I was wondering if it could also be done with 1 regex line.

Comment: Since you're reading line by line, I believe it's much more sensible to use an if clause and put the multilines in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\[(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\] MW(\d*) P(\d*) PR(\d*)\] (.{5}) - (.*) - (?P<full_message>[\s\S]*?)(?=\r?\n\[\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\]|$)
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/eJ8uC3

#### Discussion

Basically, I started up with the inital regex and I added to it the named capturing group `full_message`. This capturing group will match any char (`[\s\S]*?`) until it finds the start of the next log line preceded by a new line (`\r?\n\[\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\]`) or the end of the file (`$`).

Usually, when building this kind of regular expressions, I tend to replace spaces with (`\s` or `\s+`). This way, I ensure protecting my regex. But, if the log file format is guaranteed to not change you can ignore what I just wrote.